# Inherit window to another window xaml

Tags: wpf, window, radix, inheritance

I'm starting with WPF but I can't find the way to inherit from a window to another window.

Now, I'm starting a new application on WinForm in which I created a generic window to add/edit/remove/consult objects. So the windows have some buttons, a header, a footer, a background color, etc.
Then, I inherit this windows to the windows for each object.

So without doing anything, I have amost the full page ready.

My question is... Can I do the same with WPF? Because, I want to stop doing the app with Winform and start working with WPF.

I spend a lot of time looking for how to do this in WPF, but I can't find the way. I saw that WPF can't inherit the appearance.

I saw custom controls or user controls, but I need to put things inside the control that I inherit to complete the screen.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to put things inside the control that I inherit to complete the screen."?

Comment: I mean, that I define for example a window to create an object withe a header and some buttons at the bottom (for ex, create, cancel, refresh, apply, etc).

And then, I inherit that window to create a customer, a product, a company, etc. So, I have the information at the top and at the bottom of the screen and I only have to add the labels and the textboxes that I need for that specific entity.

Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF does not allow you to visually inherit in this way.

What I would suggest doing is creating a custom class that inherits from `Window`, and add `RelayCommand` properties for the different buttons you want to display on all windows.  Have the `RelayCommand`s call Virtual methods that perform the necessary logic.

Then, create a custom `ControlTemplate` (make it the default so any custom window will use this tempalte) for your custom `Window` which includes a Header or Footer section that has the buttons you want to include on all windows.  You can then `DataBind` these buttons to the `Command`s in your custom window class (perhaps through a `RelativeSource` `Self` binding).

This approach should allow you to create windows that have a "shared" footer, but different content.  If you're fairly new to WPF, this might be a little tricky.  Another approach would be to create a `UserControl` that implements the Header/Footer functionality and raises events for the button actions, then just drop it on all your windows.  But this approach fails to leverage the power of WPF, specifically the lookless nature of controls, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You need to declare your new class as public (actually this to ensure both classes have the same reach)

```
public class newWindow : Window
```

Then, inherit from your new class

```
public partial class TestClass : newWindow
```

Then, modify the TestClass xaml file:

```
<base:newWindow>
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
xmlns:base="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
</base:newWindow>
```